# Sorting counts in descending order

Tags: sorting, words, counter

Have the following code that counts the number of times words are used.  I want to list the results sorted by the number of counts.

```lisp
    (defun rk-word-analysis (reg-beg reg-end)
      "Count times words are used in a region, ignoring punctuation."
    
      (interactive "r")
    
      (let ($words)
    
        (save-excursion
          (goto-char reg-beg)
          (while (re-search-forward "\\w+" reg-end t)
        (let* (($word (intern (match-string 0)))
               ($cell (assq $word $words)))
          (if $cell
              (setcdr $cell (1+ (cdr $cell)))
            (setq $words (cons (cons $word 1) $words))))))
        (when (interactive-p)
          (message "%S" $words))
    
        $words))
```

Comment: `C-h f sort` tells you how to sort a list, using a predicate of your choice.

Comment: I need some elaboration for sorting the $words list.  Gone with `(sort $words '<)`, which gets sort to complain with `sort: Wrong type argument: number-or-marker-p, (This . 1)`

Comment: Was the elaboration in the answer enough?

Comment: The elaboration is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `sort` function with the appropriate predicate. Since the list that you want to sort is a list of pairs, `(word . count)`, you cannot compare using `<` which can only compare numbers: `(< '("foo" . 3) '("bar" . 7))` does not work because `<` cannot compare pairs. Since you want to sort the list by increasing order of the `count`, you have to select the `count` part to compare. So the appropriate predicate would be:

```el
(lambda (x y) (< (cdr x) (cdr y))
```

In other words, to compare `x` and `y`, you take the `cdr` of each (i.e. the `count` part of the pair) and compare them with `<` - this works since you are comparing numbers.

Here's an example of how to call `sort`:

```el
;; initialize $words
(setq $words '(("foo" . 5) ("bar" . 3) ("baz" . 4)))
(("foo" . 5) ("bar" . 3) ("baz" . 4))

;; sort the list according to the predicate
(setq sorted-list (sort $words (lambda (x y) (< (cdr x) (cdr y)))))
(("bar" . 3) ("baz" . 4) ("foo" . 5))

;; how the sorted list looks
sorted-list
(("bar" . 3) ("baz" . 4) ("foo" . 5))
```

EDIT: This is obviously *ascending* order. For descending order, replace `<` with `>` in the predicate.